# String to Timestamp conversion difference error in Java

Tags: java, string, timestamp, date-conversion, sql-timestamp

I have the following value:
2018-01-16-18.56.57.300000

It is passed to the method parameter: "value".

```
private Timestamp getPossibleTimestampI(String value) {

   SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss.SSS");
    Date parsedDate;
    Timestamp timestamp=null; 
    try {
        parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(value);
        timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

return timestamp;
}
```

I am getting a Timestamp object with the value of 2018-01-16 19:01:57.0, about 5 minutes more compared to the original string value.

Why is this happening, and how can I correct my conversion?

Comment: How many minutes is `300000` milliseconds?

Comment: Gosh, thanks...I guess  I should go home today...

Comment: You are using terrible old classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

Comment: Tip: learn about standard ISO 8601 formats.

Comment: You shouldn’t be wanting a `Timestamp` at all. That class is outdated and filled with design problems. For saving into your database use an `Instant` or if circumstances dictate, a `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, the thing is, I am obliged to use an older JDK unfortunately...

Comment: Since an older JDK (like version 6 or 7) cannot parse your string, I suggest you use the backport of java.time, [the ThreeTen Backport library](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), it can. Only you will have to use its `DateTimeUtils.toTimestamp` method for converting to a `Timestamp` for your database.

Comment: I am not allowed to use third party libraries as well, the policy is quite strict..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Time 2018-01-16-18.56.57.300000, Your 300000 milliseconds are being converted to minutes

```
which is 300000/60000 = 5 minutes
```

Comment: _and how can I correct my conversion?_

Comment: Remove miliseconds before conversion.